# no matter what i do sonar refused to go beyond Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in jenkins

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to set up devops and have reached up-to sonarQube integration in jenkins. Now its not moving beyond "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0". I had java 1.8 but i installed 1.7 to remove this error. Still coming. Changed java version (checked in command line as well). JAVA_HOME, PATH, all those variable point to java 1.7. Still coming. I can run analysis on sonarqube server, if i try separately (localhost:9000) but in jenkins it's just refusing to go beyond this message. I am not from java background so i might be missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM used to run the job must be >=Java 8. Whether or not you had it installed, the error you're getting indicates that Java 8 wasn't being used by the job.

Comment: Thanks Ann. I figured it out. After making both point to java 8, it worked. Thanks again.